# Glossy shadder work differently on two obejcts

Tags: shaders

I did face and after that I did retopology. And now glossy shader on lowpoly mesh is working differently than on other objects. Anyone know why is this happening? I didn't change anything in any options.
I just saw that this is not glossy shader problem but fresnal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the answer. I had to flip normals.